# Creating a dapps

Tags: blockchain, dapp-development, dapps, ethereumjs, pyethereum

I'd like to create an ethereum based dapp and coin, looking trough the code for some popular projects I could see they mostly use python but I couldn't find any solidity code. 
Is this normal? How is the integration between the python and ethereum done? Can I use js and node? 
Are there any good guides for an experienced developer getting started with ethereum? 
Thanks

Comment: Hi there. There are a couple of Python-based contracting languages - Serpent and Viper - but I suspect you've either stumbled across a project that uses a Python-based web framework somehow (e.g. Flask), or you're looking at either a client implementation or EVM written in Python. Either way, this is a very broad question that is answered as well as it can be by the linked I've duped your question to. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, it does! I'll read up on the resources in the link. Also what are the pros and cons of building on ethereum vs building mu own blockchain? Apart from security?